# Preventing the same IP from executing an action for 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

So I've been programming this thing that allows a user to click a button once every 24 hours and is blocked to do so in the meantime. The concrete example is a vote script that should only allow a vote every 24 hours (albeit a user can vote for the same thing again).

So what I did was create a timelimit table in MySql

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `timelimit` (
  `ipaddress` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `ipdate` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ipaddress`) )
ENGINE = MyIsam;
```

The IP-address is a string because I was too lazy to convert it to a proper integer format and  it should allow for IPv6 addresses, too. Also there's no 128 bit integer, is there?

I'll leave the other table that saves the votings out, I don't think it's in the scope of this question.

So my issue is... random. Some people couldnt vote for days straight, for example. Also we saw a rapid increase (a few hundred) in one day once. We suppose though that was the work of a bot, since this script doesn't yet have any security in terms of verifying if that actually was a click by a user (and it's pointless, because everything can be done by bots. Just a matter of making it harder).

I just voted today and tried again, the program told me I can vote again in... 0 hours and 59 minutes... It should rather be 23 hours and 59 minutes!

Something is so wrong here and I can't put my finger on it. At all!

```
$oneday = 86400;
$ip = trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
require_once "config.php";
$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
mysql_select_db($mysql_db);
//I apologize for still using mysql_
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection error!");
}

mysql_query("SET time_zone='+0:00';"); // This helped me fix some issues because the field is DateTime

$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `timelimit` WHERE ipdate <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `ipaddress` = '$ip';"); 
/* supposed to count if there is any entry corresponding 
   to the IP address wihich is in the blocked timeframe. 
   Could be the source of an error, but I can't put my finger on it... */

if (mysql_result($res,0) > 0)   {
    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ipdate) as ipdate FROM timelimit WHERE ipaddress = '$ip';");
    $lastvote = mysql_result($res2, 0, "ipdate");
    $nextvote = $lastvote + $oneday;
    $timebetween = time() - $lastvote;
    $timetonext = $nextvote - time();
        //Some calculations done for the sake of output.
    die("You can only vote once a day. You can vote again in " . date("H", $timetonext) . " hours and " . date("i", $timetonext) . " minutes");
} else {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['postid'])) {
        $postid = $_REQUEST['postid'];
        $postid = mysql_real_escape_string($postid);

        if (!is_numeric($postid)) {
            die("post id not valid");
        } //The input would be sanitized by now (I hope?)

                //VOTE IS VALID
                //*SNIP* voting logic (increases the counter with an UPDATE table SET votes = votes + 1)
                //Done with the voting, time limit logic again:

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `timelimit` WHERE ipaddress = '$ip';");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `timelimit` (`ipaddress`, `ipdate`) VALUES ('$ip', UTC_TIMESTAMP);"); 
// Could probably be combined into an INSERT and ON EXIST UPDATE query.
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're setting $oneday. Also, consider selecting the date rather than using COUNT(*) so that you only have to make a single trip to the database if they're blocked. Also, consider `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` rather than `DELETE` then `INSERT`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams $oneday is set in the first line of the code :) I already considered the last thing... Hmm, maybe I'll even just use the FloodControl in PEAR if I can't find it out

Answer (score 1):

Use [PEAR FloodControl](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_FloodControl/) it does everything for you.

Example taken from http://www.tozalakyan.com/fc/index.php#db

```
CREATE TABLE fc_logs (
    unique_id varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    data text NOT NULL,
    access int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (unique_id)
)
```

.

```
require_once 'HTTP/FloodControl.php';
try {
    $ip = HTTP_FloodControl::getUserIP();
} catch (HTTP_FloodControl_Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}
try {
    $fc =& new HTTP_FloodControl();
    $fc->setContainer('MDB2', array(
        'dsn' => 'mysql://username:password@localhost/dbname',
        'table' => 'fc_logs',
        'autooptimize' => true
    ));
    $limits = array (
        86400 => 10       // maximum 10 requests in 24 h
    );
    if (!$fc->check($limits, $ip)) {
        die('Too many requests. Please try later.');
    }
} catch (HTTP_FloodControl_Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}
// Your code...
```

Requirements and Dependencies:

- PHP 5
- PEAR::Exception
- PEAR::DB (optional)
- PEAR::MDB (optional)
- PEAR::MDB2 (optional)